# 3 days test - upgrading to Pro via In-App Purchase

Tags: java, android, android-studio, countdowntimer

I'm looking for some ways to make an app that every body can use all the futures for just 3 days, after the limited time ends some of futures disables but again via In-App Purchase they will ready to use.

The question is, How can I set a timer to count down for 3 days from the time that application for first time opened? I should do it in some way that when the phone power offs there mustn't be problem.again after powering on and without opening the app it should count down to 00:00:00.

Is there any samples for this? Or how can I do it?

Comment: When they first use the app, set a timestamp. Every time they use the app, make a check to see if the current date is 3 days greater than that timestamp.

Comment: no i want it to be exactly 3 day,like this.
 time left : 2d and 06:37:26

Comment: Yep, and every time the app opens, recalculate how long it's been since the timestamp by using the current time, and display how much time is left.

Comment: I think it's a good way,But I don't know how to do this.is there any samples for this?You know,I'm beginner in JAVA :D

Answer (score 0):

As @4castle said, set a time stamp when they first open the app. Then, if you want to display a countdown with an exact time until expiration, have a text box somewhere that displays time remaining. [Calendar](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#clone())

```
import java.util.Calendar

if( this.firstTimeRunning() ){
Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance(); 
//save start.getTimeInMillis()
}

Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
end.setTimeInMillis( /* saved millisec value */);
end.set(Calendar.DAY, end.get(Calendar.DAY) + 3);
long difference = end.getTimeInMillis() - start.getTimeInMillis();

text_box.setText(/* format difference*/); //update every second
```

Something like that.

Comment: I have a question here.after the time expired, if the user changes his/her mobiles time and data, lets say 2 days before, what will happen?the timer starts counting down again?

Comment: The timer wouldn't know. You could add a check though. If current time is before start, end trial. Otherwise, yeah the user could reset their time everyday to the day they start the app. I think the only way around that is to use the web and ask your server (or use an online API) what time it is when you start the app.